# Создание двумерного массива в ассемблере

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Как создать двумерный массив (NxN) в ассемблере? Проблема в том, что размерность должен ввести пользователь.

Comment: В каком ассемблере?

Comment: В данном случае рассматривается только MASM

Comment: Для решения вашей задачи диалект не важен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учетом того, что нужно создать массив динамически, можно подключить библиотеку `msvcrt` (или `libc` под *nix) и использовать функции `scanf` и `malloc` оттуда.

Пример кода для fasm (для masm суть будет та же самая):

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable
scanf_format_string db '%d',0
n dd ?
matrix dd ?

section '.code' code readable executable
start:
    cinvoke scanf, scanf_format_string, n
    mov eax, [n]
    mul eax ; Будем выделяем память на n * n элементов
    lea eax, [eax*4] ; Домножаем на размер элемента (будем считать, что это dword - 4 байта)
    cinvoke malloc, eax ; Выделяем память
    mov [matrix], eax ; Сохраняем полученный адрес
    ; ...
    cinvoke free, [matrix] ; Освобождаем память
    invoke ExitProcess,0

section '.idata' import data readable

library kernel, 'kernel32.dll',\
        msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel,\
        ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'

import msvcrt,\
        scanf,'scanf',\
        malloc,'malloc',\
        free,'free'
```

Адреса внутри массива придется вычислять самостоятельно как `(i * n + j) * 4`, где *i* и *j* - соответственно, номер строки и столбца (считая с 0).

Answer (score 0):

> Как создать двумерный массив (NxN) в ассемблере?

Точно так же, как и в любом другом языке: выделить память NxN. Ну или сначала определиться, что для вас значит "двумерный массив".

```
section .data
dvumernii_massiv      db  1, 2,  9, 4
                      db  5, 14, 7, 8
                      db  9, 10, 14,14
```

Так сойдёт?

Comment: так мы заранее определяем размерность, в данном случае 4 на 3. А проблема стоит в том, чтобы выделить место под массив размерности, которую введет пользователь. То есть он должен динамически создаваться

Comment: Ну так и сформулируйте это на НОРМАЛЬНОМ ЯЗЫКЕ. В первую очередь для себя. Потом на алгоритмическом: "выделить память для N адресов массива". "От 0 до N-1 выделить память для новых массивов, размером N". "Записать  значения полученых адресов в соответствующие элементы первого массива N". Done? Вот тогда уже и переводите на ассемблер. Предварительно не забыв освежить знания по выбранному вами диалекту. Или, по-вашему, ассемблер - эта такая мешанина из инструкций, где думать не надо?

Comment: Написал простейшую программу на С, решающая данную задачу (https://ideone.com/eeGknC). Требуется написать программу на ассемблере, реализующую данный алгоритм:
1. Получили размерность
2. Выделили место
3. Заполнили чем-угодно
4. Вывели на экран.
Вот ассемблер-то я и не знаю, пробовал искать какие-то ресурсы, но большинство примеров работы с массивом упирается в то, что массив задается в разделе .data и он всегда определенной размерности.

Comment: "*Вот ассемблер-то я и не знаю*" - так кто мешает узнать? Или надеетесь, что тут вам начнут зачитывать вслух и с художественным присвистом учебники? С другой стороны, раз вы не соотностие код на C и что происходит в компьютере на самом деле, значит, надо ещё раз вернуться назад. И написать на бумажке, по клеточкам расписывая содержание байтиков памяти, а по столбцам каждую инструкцию вашего C-кода.

Comment: Хорошо, конкретизирую вопрос: Как выделить участок памяти размером N*(4 байт) в сегменте кода? Какие инструкции для этого следует рассмотреть?

Comment: А что вам доступно? Диапазон широчайший 1) выделение памяти в .data или .bss заранее 2) функции стандартной библиотеки под вашу OS/компилятор 3) написание аллокатора самостоятельно.

Comment: "*участок памяти размером N*(4 байт) в сегменте кода?*" это не описка? Именно в сегменте кода, и речь идёт о современных ОС, а не об окаменелостях уровня `dos/model tiny`?

Comment: Размерность массива задается пользователем с клавиатуры, поэтому вариант с выделением памяти заранее, на мой взгляд. в данном случае невозможен. Писать собственный аллокатор не позволяет временные рамки для поставленной задачи, потому остается ваниант использования стандартных библиотек Windows. Возможно я ошибаюсь, но можно ли прибегнуть к помощи malloc?

Comment: OK, воспользуйтесь "стандартными библиотеками Windows". А можно и средствами стандартной библиотеки C, типа `malloc()`. До сих пор не понимаю что вам помешало это сделать. И в чём, собственно, вопрос. За вас код писать никто не будет, покажите свой.

Comment: *Размерность массива задается пользователем с клавиатуры* это, конечно, самый ограничивающий фактор. А если не с клавиатуры, а мышкой? А если из stdin программа что-то примет? А если этот размер будет задан константой в коде? Насколько принципиально изменится ВАШ алгоритм решения задачи?